# what function describes this pattern?

Tags: algorithms

Kevin is using pennies to make a pattern, he arranges the pattern as shown below

```
                   O
          O       O O
 O       O O     O O O 
Fig. 1  Fig.2    Fig.3
```

My question is what is the formula used to describe this pattern?

I have started by mapping out a table

```
    1 | 1
    2 | 3
    3 | 6
    4 | 10
    5 | 15
```

my first notion is to start with (N+1) since the bottom increases by 1 each time, now however i am stuck, where should i go from here?

Comment: You are close. How about something like $a_{n+1} = a_n + n + 1$, with $a_1 = 1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{l}1\mapsto 1\\
2\mapsto 1+2\\
3\mapsto 1+2+3\\
\vdots\\
n\mapsto ?
\end{array}$$

Can you find the formula?

Comment: its n plus the previous result? i am just unsure how to represent the previous result in this case.

Comment: If you want to use a recurrence relation, @Shailesh gave you a hint. If I were in your shoes, I would define the function $f(n)$ directly.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notation "$\sum$" (sum)?